# How to calculate cointegrations of two lists?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

Thank you in advance for your help!

I have two lists with some stocks prices, example:

```
a = [10.23, 11.65, 12.36, 12.96]

b = [5.23, 6.10, 8.3, 4.98]
```

I can calculate the **correlation** of these two lists, with:

```
import scipy.stats

scipy.stats.pearsonr(a, b)[0]
```

But, I didn't found a method to calculate the co-integration of two lists.

Could you give me some advices?

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186994/johansen-cointegration-test-in-python

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe a cointegration test has been implemented for scipy. You may be better off [using `rpy2`](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) to interface Python with R. R provides cointegration tests in the [`urca` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urca/index.html).

For example:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
r=ro.r

a = [10.23, 11.65, 12.36, 12.96]
b = [5.23, 6.10, 8.3, 4.98]
```

Define `a` and `b` in R:

```
ro.globalEnv['a']=ro.FloatVector(a)
ro.globalEnv['b']=ro.FloatVector(b)
```

Call the R `cor` (correlation) function:

```
print(r('cor(a,b,method="pearson")'))
# [1] 0.2438518
```

Call the R `ca.po` (Phillips & Ouliaris Cointegration Test)

```
r('library(urca)')
print(r('ca.po(cbind(a,b))'))
# ######################################################## 
# # Phillips and Ouliaris Unit Root / Cointegration Test # 
# ######################################################## 

# The value of the test statistic is: 0
```

I'm not familiar with cointegration, however, so apologies if my use of `ca.po` is totally inept.

Also note that R is programming language unto itself, with (at least currently) a richer library of statistical functions than `scipy`. It's possible to run R directly (without Python). The calls would look a little simpler:

```
> a = c(10.23, 11.65, 12.36, 12.96)
> b = c(5.23, 6.10, 8.3, 4.98)
> z = cbind(a,b)
> z
         a    b
[1,] 10.23 5.23
[2,] 11.65 6.10
[3,] 12.36 8.30
[4,] 12.96 4.98
> ca.po(z)

######################################################## 
# Phillips and Ouliaris Unit Root / Cointegration Test # 
######################################################## 

The value of the test statistic is: 0
```

Comment: Please, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this statsmodels pull request http://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/453

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice example of testing for cointegration at http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mapsa/seminario-doc-2014/blob/master/cointegration-example.ipynb