# Johansen cointegration test in python

Tags: python, statistics, pandas, statsmodels

I can't find any reference on funcionality to perform Johansen cointegration test in any Python module dealing with statistics and time series analysis (pandas and statsmodel). Does anybody know if there's some code around that can perform such a test for cointegration among time series?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

statsmodels doesn't have a Johansen cointegration test. And, I have never seen it in any other python package either.

statsmodels has VAR and structural VAR, but no VECM (vector error correction models) yet.

*update:*

As Wes mentioned, there is now a pull request for Johansen's cointegration test for statsmodels. I have translated the matlab version in LeSage's spatial econometrics toolbox and wrote a set of tests to verify that we get the same results. 
It should be available in the next release of statsmodels.

*update 2:*

The test for cointegration `coint_johansen` was included in statsmodels 0.9.0 together with the vector error correction models VECM.
(see also 3rd answer)

Answer (score 16):

This is now implemented in Python's statsmodels:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen
x = getx() # dataframe of n series for cointegration analysis
jres = coint_johansen(x, det_order=0, k_ar_diff=1)
```

For a full description of inputs/results, see [the documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen.html).

Comment: The documentation is COMPLETELY WORtHLESS

Answer (score 4):

See http://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/453

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/88477497/

It provides a library where you can find the Johansen cointegration test.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.